# Kotlin - An interface for pairs

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, and unsure how to abstract the following.

So for example I have this:

```
metadataOf(
   "sId" to "123",
   "uId" to "456"
)
```

where `metadataOf()` looks like this

```
fun <VALUE> metadataOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, VALUE>) =
    MetaData.from(pairs.toMap())!!
```

I'd like that

```
metadataOf(
   "sId" to "123",
   "uId" to "456"
)
```

To be standarised, so say something like `metadata.message` or `metadataFrom(message)` would produce those 2 pairs for me. (And of course in the future if I added more and I could easily do so in one place)

How would I go about writing this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you really just wanted a `data class SMetadata(val sId: String, val uId: String)` and a `metadataOf(vararg sMetadatas: SMetaData)`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you really wanted is:

```
data class SMetadata(val sId: String, val uId: String)
```

and

```
//fun metadataOf(vararg sMetadatas: SMetaData) =
//    MetaData.from(sMetaDatas.map { mapOf("sId" to it.sId, "uId" to it.uId) })
```

and

```
//metadataOf(
//   SMetaData(sId = "123", uId = "456")
//)
```

**EDIT:** apparently all you *really* wanted was

```
fun SMetaData.toMetaData() = MetaData.from(mapOf("sId" to sId, "uId" to uId))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - thinking about it, I need to go about it another way - where I just create that pair. I've updated my original post.

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case, I don't understand the question, which means I can't provide an answer. :/

Comment: Are those typos: `fun metadataOf(vararg sMetadatas: SMetadata) =
    MetaData.from(sMetadatas.map { mapOf("sId" to it.sId, "uId" to it.uId) })` as I still get the error - `required (Mutable)Map<String!, *>, found List<Map<String, String>>`

Comment: In that case you probably just wanted a data class and an extension function.

Comment: You commented below: "Sure, but what does this provide over the built-in `Pair<S, T>`?" - What does `SMetaData` provide over the built-in `Pair<S, T>`?

Comment: @MatthewLayton the name `sId` and `uId`, as it is expected in languages with static types and the ability to provide names for variables?

Answer (score -1):

You can make your own `Pair` implementation along with an `infix` function, lets call it `MyPair` and give it the same implementation as the original one:

```
fun main() {
    listOf(
        "s1" pair "s2",
        "k1" pair "k2"
    )
}

public data class MyPair<out A, out B>(
    public val first: A,
    public val second: B
) : Serializable {
    public override fun toString(): String = "($first, $second)"
}

public infix fun <A, B> A.pair(that: B): MyPair<A, B> = MyPair(this, that)
```

Comment: Sure, but what does this provide over the built-in `Pair<S, T>`?

Comment: From the original question my understanding was that they needed their own "custom" `Pair` so they can make changes to it if needed. Seems that wasn't the case.