# Kotlin - Returning list of Pair

Tags: kotlin

In a Kotlin app, I have this method:

```
fun <VALUE> metadataOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, VALUE>) =
    MetaData.from(pairs.toMap())!!
```

Which I'm then using like:

```
 metadataOf(
   "sId" to message.sId,
   "userId" to message.userId
)
```

I'm trying to write a method which can create the above for me from `message` - however I'm not sure how to return a list of pairs - this is what I put together based on the input parameter from `metadataOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, VALUE>)`

```
fun metadataFrom( message: CommandMessage<Any> ): Pair<String, Any> {
     return  (
        "sId" to message.sId,
        "userId" to message.userId
        )
}
```

Comment: Is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923265/kotlin-an-interface-for-pairs?

Comment: You could make it an extension function of `CommandMessage<*>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices here.

1. Using `List`:

```kotlin
fun metadataFrom(message: CommandMessage<Any>): List<Pair<String, Any>> = listOf(
  "sId" to message.sId,
  "userId" to message.userId
)
```

You can use it in this way:

```kotlin
val result = metadataFrom(message)
metadataOf(*result.toTypedArray())
```

2. Using `Array`:

```kotlin
fun metadataFrom(message: CommandMessage<Any>): Array<Pair<String, Any>> = arrayOf(
  "sId" to message.sId,
  "userId" to message.userId
)
```

You can use it in this way:

```kotlin
val result = metadataFrom(message)
metadataOf(*result)
```

The second is more performant since you are directly creating the array used as input for `metadataOf` but nothing noticeable if you haven't a huge amount of data. So choose your favorite one.

Comment: Thanks - why is the `*` important in `metadataOf(*result))`?

Comment: No problem. It's the spread operator. Since you are accepting a `vararg` in `metadataOf()`, you should pass the arguments one-by-one. The spread operator is used to pass the content of the array one-by-one to the function.